# moving from twig to ReactJS: how to extend a template/component to build full reactJS pages? implement react-router and redux into symfony?

Tags: symfony, reactjs, twig

In my twig application, I have a controller rendering a view.

This view is as follows:

```
{% extends ':Template/Backend:backend.html.twig' %}

{% block title_wrapper %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
 My code
{% endblock %}
```

In backend.html.twig, I have :

```
{% extends ':Template/base.html.twig' %}

{% block navbar %}
   {% render controller ... %}
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar%}
   {% render controller ... %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now, this page is super dynamic with many different ajax calls updating different part of the data. ReactJS seems to be the good way to make it simpler.

I understand how to put one component inside another one and build up on that.
However, with content of my navbar and my sidebar depending on the content of my page, how do I make it work ?

My issues are :

1. If I render my body component and it is separated from my navbar and sidebar components (keep existing twig structure and load 3 components), a change in one won't update the other one
2. If I load one single app component which includes navbar, sidebar and body components, how do I make variations of the body i.e. how do I replicate the 'extends' feature of twig?
3. I need to move step by step so I need to keep rendering parts of my application with twig
4. It looks like I would need to implement correctly reux and react-router in my symfony application, create a single page app and an app component which includes navbars. I'd appreciate some help ont that !

Would love some help from a reactJS expert! Thanks!

Comment: Investiggating this, I have the impression I need to properly implement Redux so I would have one single store on which all my components depend. They users actions in my view would trigger events to which subsets of the store have subscribed. That way the data update is cycling down on every component... still trying to get it right

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byoigres/yx50k53z/), with `react-router` you can separate each page and create components, layouts and views.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={AppContainer}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomeView} />
      <Route path="list" component={ListView} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Create two views, `home` and `list`, they may look like this:

```
class HomeView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MainLayout
        sidebarTitle="Links"
        sidebar={<SidebarList />}>
        Hello world! This is the HomeView!
      </MainLayout>
    );
  }
}
```

Inside each view `extends` from a layout and pass the properties like what component we need to be a `sidebar` and a `children`.

```
class ListView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <MainLayout
        sidebarTitle="Text"
        sidebar={<SidebarText />}>
        <h1>List</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
      </MainLayout>
    );
  }
}
```

In the layout use that properties to display the content in as you do with twig.

```
class MainLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar
          title="APP"
        />
        <div>
          <div>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
          <div>
            {this.props.sidebar}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe it's a little bit confusing but you need to take a look at the fiddle, it's the closer I can do based on your example.

Comment: nice, thanks, this is the behaviour I was missing. I'll build up on that example.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you start small to get the hang of how ReactJS works. You can easily use ReactJS for only a limited portion of your app.

Let's say you want to change a component of your app that sits inside a div with id "myComponent". You can put a script on your page that makes this into a ReactJS component (ES6 syntax):

```
import MyComponent from './mycomponent';
ReactDOM.render( <MyComponent />, document.getElementById('myComponent'));
```

In this code, `<MyComponent />` signifies your main React Component in the mycomponent.js file in the same folder. For one small component, you won't need Redux stores; simply store all state in the component's `this.state`. When adding more components that re-use the same state, Redux is a very nice way to go about this.

Note that you will need some extra setup to get the simple example to work.  `<MyComponent />` is JSX, not plain Javascript. You need a transpiler like Babel to convert this into plain js (and as a bonus, it also supports ES6 notations). Also, don't forget to include React and React-Dom!

Comment: well, I've said I was ok with this... That's not an answer to my question, I want to go beyond the basics and render many different components. i need to mimic the extend and include features of twig